# SharePoint Workflow defaulted to Approved

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-tasks-list

Can anyone please let me know why the SharePoint Workflow tasks defaulted "Approved"? Is there any reason behind this?

Is this okay to add "Not Started" and set as default in the Task Outcome column. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an approval workflow is started, the Status of the task shows "Not Started":
[image]

If the approver approve or reject the task, the Status will show "Completed" and the Outcome show "Approved" or "Rejected". It is by default.

[image]

You can set your own Outcome values with SharePoint Designer.

If you are using SharePoint 2010 workflow, you can refer to [it](http://eimagine.com/approve-or-reject-what-about-a-third-option-in-sharepoint-2010-approval-workflows/).

If you are using SharePoint 2013 workflow, you can refer to [it](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-custom-task-outcomes-in-sharepoint-2013-designer-workflow-and-how/).